# Superclass with XIB and its subclass with XIB?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, xib

In my UI, there are three different table view cells. Well,not THAT different, they have some elements in common. So a base class capturing common elements would be in order.

How to apply basic OOP principles when I have the base class with XIB file?
How would I then add missing differing elements in respective subclasses if they ALSO have XIB files? (I want them to have XIB files as I am too lazy to edit frames and other properties of those elements in code..who has time for that nowadays...)

I mean how do I solve this superXIB - subXIB relationship thing?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.. But there is no way you can load multiple xibs from the bundle for a view or merge multiple xibs into one! :)

So I think you cannot have a superXIB - subXIB relationship.

You can create a base Table cell with no xib, containing some common things. Other tableview cells derive this. Have separate xib's for these subviews so that you can set frame and stuff.